# Business agreement between a doctor and a reputed drug company is halal or haram?

Tags: halal-haram, finance

I need a suggestion from you based on the following scenario:
"Suppose, Dr.X is working in a private hospital. He makes a business agreement with one of the best companies of a country which exports drugs to the developed country. According to agreement, Dr.X will write a specific drug for a specific disease which is produced by the aforementioned renowned company. The price of the drug is similar to the price of other companies and quality is superior or similar to other companies. As an agreement the doctor will get a monthly salary from that company. Dr.X will write the drug in his prescription according to disease condition/according to need'. Is it permissible to make such a business agreement with the company and earn money?